# Fastest way to code up a quick CRUD app. when I have some reusable java code?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, crud

I have to come up with a basic CRUD app. as fast as possible (and by "fast" I mean like 3 days).

I considered going with Django, but I don't have a lot of experience with Python/Django, and also I have a complete set of EntityBeans that I need do CRUD on. So I thought reusing them would be better.

The resulting CRUD app. should be similar to the Django admin page (but the Django admin page per-se won't work though).

Is there some framework with which I can start with EntityBeans and get a quick, Django admin like skeleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must try AppFuse or Spring Roo.

http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Demos+and+Videos (+online demo)

http://spring.io/

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change a technology stack you're working on and still have an **Django-like administration interface**, there is a Java alternative - [LightAdmin](http://lightadmin.org) all-in-one library.

After declaring Maven dependency & enabling administration panel in your web.xml, you will have a complete CRUD with some additional features, like filtering, scopes, security, etc.
The only code related to data administration in your codebase would be DSL configurations for UI customization.

The only thing is that **LightAdmin** could be used only for **JPA domain model entities** administration for now.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [playframework](http://www.playframework.org/) as it is easy to learn and quick to get up and running. They have a [CRUD administration module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.3/crud) you can use to generate CRUD framework based on your Entity model. Also check out their [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.3/guide7) page.

Answer (score 2):

[Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo/start) gives you a CRUD application up in 10 minutes. Unlike other frameworks this really is practically usable.

I have downloaded the Roo shell for the first time and without reading any documentation I managed to get an application up and running within minutes.

Answer (score 1):

[Naked Objects](http://www.nakedobjects.org/), if you're look at a prototype. Although it does have a "viewer" for Wicket apart from the [HTML viewer](http://www.nakedobjects.org/plugins/html-viewer/index.html), I would recommend using the framework primarily for fleshing out the functionality of your domain.

You might also want to check the [Scimpi viewer](http://www.nakedobjects.org/plugins/scimpi/index.html), although I must admit that I havent worked with it.

[A demo application](http://www.nakedobjects.org/demo.html) using the HTML viewer is hosted online, and is accessible for having a quick look at the functionality. [A tutorial demo](http://www.nakedobjects.org/tutorial-movies.html) is also hosted online.

Answer (score 1):

Give [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) about 2 hours, and if you don't have a CRUD app after that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've used CodeCharge Studio by Yes Software for several years, and am able to build a CRUD app in less than 10 minutes (assuming database already exists). CodeCharge has a bit of a learning curve if you want to go beyond the interfaces created by the wizards, yet I think my development time has increased by a factor of at least 30 from writing my own code.

I use it at work to create PHP applications that hit MSSQL, and other projects that hit MySQL. Works like a charm for both.

http://www.yessoftware.com/index2.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not a "pythonista" so this may be absolute rubbish but could Django running on Java be the answer for you?

Jython is an implementation of python for the JVM and can run Django.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/

Answer (score 0):

Yes Java has many such framework for both web and desktop but .net has very few..

I recently used [RocketFramework](http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/) , which was to my expectation.. So just thought to post it here so that anybody interested have the link :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Quick Crude App in minutes using HTML5, i found www.quickcrud.com that allows you to generate the HTML5 on line and also it's possible to generate Android Apk also in minutes!